# cannot pass string variable to function

Tags: php

When I am trying to run this code the variable $column it's not passing. But instead if I use a string (eg "ABC") it gets passed. What's wrong?

```
(a) calling function
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    if(PMA_SQP_isKeyWord($column)) {

(b) called function
function PMA_SQP_isKeyWord($column) {
```

Comment: what does a var_dump of $columns look like just above your foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Using `functions` for conditional statements require to return BOOLEAN after performing task. If it satisfies your criteria then return function and tell the conditional statement. Echoing strings and other methods or functions will not work If used. You should also check whether `$columns` is defined accordingly and is also an array because `foreach` only operates on arrays.